# Get State of Toggle Button in Another Running Android App

Tags: java, android

I am writing an App (**MyApp**) in Tasker that would need to read the State of a Toggle Button in another App (**AppB**) that I haven't written. It's for reporting purposes. I am a seasoned programmer, but are new to Android. Please bear that in mind:-)

Tasker have support for Java code, and have access to the full SDK of my Android 4.3 Phone.
The app will run on Android 4.3+.

I am already using AutoInput that is perfectly capable of getting the ID of widgets (Buttons etc) in other Apps, and AutoInput is also capable of Pressing these Buttons (AutoInput Accessibility must be turned ON). AutoInput will have support for what I am asking later, but I badly need it now!

**So the question is:**

How can **MyApp** get the State of a Toggle Button (with ID "toggle") in **AppB** using Java?

Comment: Tasker's AutoInput apparently does this with [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this will not be possible by easy means. The applications in Android are isolated and cannot ask for others' applications controls due to the security policy. Without the access to the AppB code and possibility to change it this will not be possible.

The AppB would have to share the state of the toggle to your app: either via content provider or simple intent each time the toggle is changed. This requires changes in AppB code which I assume is not possible in your case. I see no other way to get around this.

Comment: It must be Possible: I am already using AutoInput to Push the Buttons of AppB from MyApp! All I now want to do, is to Read the State of a Button in AppB. 

As "Mike M." states above:  "Tasker's AutoInput apparently does this with AccessibilityService."

Comment: Even if this is possible it is hacking. This is against the Android policy that all applications are isolated from each other. You should not access other applications' components.

Comment: Sure it is "hacking": Wouldn't it be possible using Accessibility given that MyApp asks the user to confirm particular Accessibility features? I think that is what AutoInput does.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing an App (MyApp) in Tasker that would need to read the
>   State of a Toggle Button in **another App (AppB) that I haven't
>   written**

In Android, by default each of the application runs in its own process and each app is **Sand-Boxed**.

Therefore, **you cannot read the data from other application until it is shared explicitly by the particular application.**

Comment: AutoInput does indeed read info about Button IDs and can also Click the very same buttons: I use it with Tasker, so I know. I just wondered how I can do a similar thing.

Comment: @gos, You would be able to click the button or enter some text for any app. But reading the app data or view state or reading the database or file system of the app is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how is then AutoInput able to read the Button Ids and also all the Texts in other Apps? Becaus that's indeed what it does: In this way, I do know the ID of the Button I want read the State of.